# I want to run script file which will move files from current directory to the shared drive in network folder.

Tags: unix, file-transfer, shell-script, shared-folders

I want to run a script file in my server which will search for .log extension file and move it to the shared drive in network.

Can you please help me on this , as i am totally new to it. However i have tried to make something but i am not sure if it is fine.

thanks

```
iwd=/IBM/fileapp/opt/linuxscriptfileread

firstpath=$(cat $iwd/pathfile | grep path1 | awk '{print $3}')
echo  "Log Path - $firstpath"

secondpath=$(cat $iwd/pathfile | grep path2 | awk '{print $3}')
echo  "Log Path - $secondpath"

thirdpath=$(cat $iwd/pathfile | grep path3 | awk '{print $3}')
echo  "Log Path - $thirdpath"

archive1=$(cat $iwd/pathfile | grep destination1 | awk '{print $3}')
echo "Archival Log Path - $archive1"

archive2=$(cat $iwd/pathfile | grep destination2 | awk '{print $3}')
echo "Archival Log Path - $archive2"

archive3=$(cat $iwd/pathfile | grep destination3 | awk '{print $3}')
echo "Archival Log Path - $archive3"

days=$(cat $iwd/pathfile | grep retentionDays  | awk '{print $3}')
echo "Retention days are - $days"

mkdir -p $archive1/$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
mkdir -p $archive2/$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
mkdir -p $archive3/$(date +"%m-%d-%y")

find $firstpath -type f -name "*.log.*" -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $archive1/$(date +"%m-%d-%y") \;
find $firstpath -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $archive1/$(date +"%m-%d-%y") \;
find $secondpath -type f -name "*.log.*" -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $archive2/$(date +"%m-%d-%y") \;
find $secondpath -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $archive2/$(date +"%m-%d-%y") \;
find $thirdpath -type f -name "*.log.*" -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $archive1/$(date +"%m-%d-%y") \;
find $thirdpath -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $archive1/$(date +"%m-%d-%y") \;

echo $(date) >> $archive1/timestamp.log
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? If you just want to move files based on their extension, a signle line `mv *.log /path/to/destination/` is enough...

Comment: HI Nathan, YEs i want to move files based on their extension which .log but not in the same server/computer. i want to move files from linux machine to windows shared drive. COuld you please help me on this . Thanks

Comment: *In theory*, just mounting the windows share in question and then `mv` your files to the mounting point. I know that some Linux distributions are compatible with Windows shares, just use `mount -t cifs //myWindowsComputer/myShareName -o username=myLogin,password=myPassword /mnt/myMountPoint`

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thanks for your reply.. sorry but i did not understand the command you said. i am new to this and hardly know which command do what..
'mount -t cifs ' i need to include this in my script it is? and '//myWindowsComputer/myShareName -o username=myLogin,password=myPassword /mnt/myMountPoint' in this my windows computer is network drive i know its ip address so shall i add ip address in place of myWindowsComputer ? also user name and password is for the windows machine? /mnt/myMountPoint what is this ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Made an answer for detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Mount the network drive

This will allow you to access the Windows network drive as if it was a folder on your Linux computer.

```
mount -t cifs //myWindowsComputer/myShareName -o username=myLogin,password=myPassword /mnt/myMountPoint
```

- `myWindowsComputer` is a name with which your Linux computer can talk to your Windows computer. **It can be its IP**, it can be its network name (aka Computer Name), the important thing is that the Linux computer can find it.
- `myShareName` is the name of your Windows share, aka the shared folder.
- `myLogin`, `mypassword` are pretty self-explainatory, they are the login and password of a Windows user allowed to access your shared folder on the Windows computer.
- `/mnt/myMountPoint` is the folder, on the Linux computer, in which the Windows share will appear. It doesnt even have to be in `/mnt`, **it just have to be an empty, existing folder**. Everything in the Windows share will appear in this folder, and everything you put in this folder will be sent to the share.

---

### 2. Make the copy

Once the share is mounted, you can make the copy as if it was a regular, local Linux folder:

```
cp /path/to/my/files/*.log /mnt/myMountPoint
```

- `/path/to/my/files/` is the path to the files you wwant to copy, of course you can remove it to copy only the files in the current workign directory.
- `/mnt/mymountPoint` same as above.

---

Obviously, you can also use any command in the mount point of the share (`ls`, `mkdir`, `touch`...) and copy your files to a subfolder of the mount point, effectively copying them in a subfolder of the Windows share.